# How do I connect an ObjectDataSource, a ListView and a DataPager?

Tags: asp.net, listview, objectdatasource

When I try to connect together an ObjectDataSource, a ListView and a DataPager, the correct values are not passed to the select method of the ObjectDataSource. -1 is always passed for `maximumRows` and 0 is passed for `startRowIndex`.

```
<asp:DataPager runat="server" ID="Address_DataPager" PageSize="50" PagedControlID="Address_ListView" >
    <Fields>
        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ShowFirstPageButton="true" ShowLastPageButton="true"
            FirstPageText="|&lt;&lt; " LastPageText=" &gt;&gt;|"
            NextPageText=" &gt; " PreviousPageText=" &lt; " />
    </Fields>
</asp:DataPager>
<asp:ListView ID="Address_ListView" runat="server"
    DataSourceID="Address_DataSource" DataKeyNames="AddressId" >
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table class="resultsGrid">
            <tr class="gridRow">
                <th scope="col">Address</th>
            </tr>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="gridRow">
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Address_Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Address") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="Address_DataSource" runat="server" TypeName="SuperApp.Business.Address"
    SelectMethod="SelectAddress" EnablePaging="True"
    MaximumRowsParameterName="maximumRows"
    StartRowIndexParameterName="startRowIndex" >
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="maximumRows"   DefaultValue="10" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="startRowIndex" DefaultValue="5"  Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

This is the select method in the `Address` class in the `SuperApp.Business` namespace:

```
System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Select, false)]
public DataTable SelectAddress(int maximumRows, int startRowIndex)
{
    if (maximumRows < 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("maximumRows", "Maximum rows should be greater than zero.");
    if (startRowIndex < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startRowIndex", "Start row index should be greater or equal to zero.");
    if (startRowIndex >= maximumRows) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startRowIndex", "Start row index should be less than the maximum rows.");

    // Would do something interesting here.
    return null;
}
```

The first exception is always thrown, as `maximumRows` is always -1. I have tried:

- Moving the DataPager into the LayoutTemplate.
- Moving the DataPager into the LayoutTemplate and removing the PagedControlID value.
- Changing the DefaultValue values to all sorts of things.
- Removing the DefaultValues from the Parameters.
- Removing the Type from the Parameters.
- Removing the SelectParameters completely.

It is probably something obvious that I just can't see. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this should be obvious.

You lack the `SelectCountMethod` on your `ObjectDataSource` so that not only the current page can be selected but also it is possible to determine how many objects are there.

A working example:

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2009/04/how-to-controll-aspnet-listview-page.html